# Batch File: Compare 2 text files and Update specific line in text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

### **Procedure:**

I have 2 text files which I am comparing line by line.

1. Check if the line is the same in both text files.
2. If not, run a procedure to do something...
3. Finally, update the line in the text file to match

The text files look something like this:

```
version_local.txt       |       version_server.txt
-----------------       |       ------------------
APP1         V5         |       APP1        V5
APP2         V5  <---   |       APP2        V8  <---
APP3         V4         |       APP3        V4
```

### **Problem**

The current solution I have creates a new line at the bottom of the text file but it does not replace the exact line.

```
@echo off

set "file=C:\APPS\version_master.txt"
set "ROOT_URL_SERVER=\\SERVER-SQL1\ClientDatabase\version_master.txt"
set "ROOT_URL_LOCAL=C:\APPS\version_master.txt"

FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('FINDSTR /rc:"\<APP2\>" %ROOT_URL_SERVER%') DO SET @Check_Server=%%a
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('FINDSTR /rc:"\<APP2\>" %ROOT_URL_LOCAL%') DO SET @Check_Local=%%a

ECHO %@Check_Local%
ECHO %@Check_Server%
ECHO ==============

REM Call Function to Update Versions
call:Update_Version_Local

:end
pause

::--------------------------------------------------------
::-- Function Update_Version_Local
::--------------------------------------------------------
:Update_Version_Local
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%i in ('type "%file%"^|find /c /v ""') do set "current=%%i"
<"%file%" >"%file%.tmp~" (
  for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%file%"^|findstr /n "^"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "delims=:" %%j in ("!line!") do if %%j EQU %current% (
      echo(!@Check_Server!
    ) else (
      echo(!line:*:=!
    )
    endlocal
  )
)
move /y "%file%.tmp~" "%file%"
goto:eof
```

**OUTPUT**

```
version_local.txt  
-----------------  
APP1         V5  
APP2         V5  
APP3         V4   
APP2         V8   <---
```

My intention is to overwrite the 2nd line in this example to look like this:

**INTENDED OUTPUT**

```
version_local.txt  
-----------------  
APP1         V5  
APP2         V8   <--- 
APP3         V4
```

Comment: why don't you just copy the server version and replace the local version?

Comment: If you want the files to be equal finally, why not simply copying one onto the other?

Comment: because I can't assume that all version updated successfully since when I do each check some procedures are run then the file is updated to match that line - then it moves to the next line. But if I update the whole file it might not have done the update for one of the lines properly right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this should do (or at least give you a good start point):

```
@echo off
setlocal 
del version_result.txt 2>nul

for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (version_local.txt) do (
   REM %%a=AppName
   REM %%b=LocalVer
   for /f "tokens=2" %%c in ('type version_server.txt ^|findstr /bic:"%%a"') do (
     REM %%c=ServerVer
     echo DEBUG [[ %%a, %%b, %%c ]]
     if "%%b" neq "%%c" call :different "%%~a" "%%~b" "%%~c"
     (if errorlevel 1 (
       REM write local version:
       echo %%a %%b
     ) else (
       REM write updated server version:
       echo %%a %%c
     )) >> version_result.txt
  )
)
echo ----
type version_result.txt
goto :eof

:different
echo Application %~1 has local version %~2 but server version %~3
echo [insert code to update]
REM if successful:
exit /b 0
REM if not successful:
exit /b 1
```

Note: the App Names should be the same in both files (Apps that are only in one of the files are ignored; order does not matter). Resulting order will be the same as in local file.